# Internal Backbone model method and update it from server

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, backbone.js

I have a simple Backbone model named 'Project'.

I would to add a method .open

This method will calls a REST api that it will change some attributes (and I receive the new json).

Is there a way to update the current model from the response? Is correct this approach?

```
var project = Backbone.Model.extend({ ...

open: function() {
... // request to the server  and update the current object... //
}

...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Backbone.Model already has a [`fetch` function](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-fetch). This can make the REST call to "fetch" the data, and on success will automatically update the model's attributes. The `fetch` function requires a `url`, which can be passed in for each call, or defined on the model. See example below.

Also, using `fetch` will have additional benefits. Example: [from fetch docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-fetch)

> Triggers a "change" event if the server's state differs from the current attributes.

This means that you can add listeners to this model's events if desired. A common pattern is to re-render a view on "update" of a model.

Additionally, `fetch` will automatically run the response through the [model's `parse` function](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-parse), which can be useful if you'd like to have a different data structure on your model than the data structure from the REST call.

Example:

```js
var Project = Backbone.Model.extend({
  url: 'my-url/to-rest-call', // defined on model
  parse: function(resp) {
    // by default, returns resp only
    // Doing this sets model attributes to resp.data object
    return resp.data;
  }
});
var project = new Project();
// runs myView's render function if updated
myView.listenTo(project, 'update', myView.render);

// now fetch using url defined on model
project.fetch();
// OR passed with call
project.fetch({
  url: 'my-other-url/to-rest-call'
});
```

Comment: `fetch` sends a GET request, it won't change the model attributes, and should not be used to change model attributes

Comment: This is true, I read the question at first as a simple fetch and update to the client model. You can certainly use `save` for a POST request to also update the server.

Answer (score 0):

> This method will calls a REST api that it will change some attributes (and I receive the new json).

If you want to update model attributes you should use [`model.save()`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-save).

> Is there a way to update the current model from the response?

`model.save()` will update the model with returned response automatically.